# Setting New-Timespan object via Function

Tags: powershell, timespan

Background: I am trying to detect whether an log entry exists. If it does, declare its string variable, otherwise continue.  Here is a portion of the script (In this order):

```
$Arch = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture

If ($Arch -eq "64-bit") {
  $SMSAgentFolder = "$env:WinDir\SysWOW64\CCM";
  $CCMSetupFolder = "$Env:Windir\CCMSetup"
} Else {
  $SMSAgentFolder = "$Env:WinDir\System32\CCM";
  $CCMSetupFolder = "$Env:Windir\System32\CCMSetup"
}

New-Variable HinvStrWarning -Value "Warning! There is not a Hardware Inventory entry listed in the Inventory Agent Log file."

Function SetHinv {
  $Hinv = Select-String $Hinvpattern $Invfile | select -Last 1 | % {
    $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value + ' ' + $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
  }
}

Function SetTSSinv {
  $TSSInv = (New-TimeSpan $Sinv).Days
}

$InvFile = "$SMSAgentFolder\logs\inventoryagent.log"

$Hinvpattern = 'HinvEndpoint.*<time="(.*?)" date="(.*?)"'

$Hinv = Select-String $Hinvpattern $InvFile | select -Last 1 | % {
  $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value + ' ' + $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
}

If(![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Hinv)) {
  SetHinv; SetTSHinv
} else {
  Add-Content $verboseLog "$HinvStrWarning"
}
```

The function `Function SetTSSinv {$TSSInv = (New-TimeSpan $Sinv).Days}` does not work by calling the function name but if you manually do it like this: `$TSSInv = (New-TimeSpan $Sinv).Days`, it does it no problem.

That was as far as I have gotten in my troubleshooting, so the additional code here may be incorrect:

Add'l Declarations:

```
$7Days = $GetDate.AddDays(7) 
$SMSCli = [wmiclass] "\\$Env:ComputerName\root\ccm:SMS_Client"
```

Functions:

```
Function SinvScan {$SMSCli.TriggerSchedule("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002}")} 
Function SinvStr {If (((($GetDate).Days) - $TSSinv) -ge $7Days){Add-Content $VerboseLog $InvLogSinvScn; SinvScan}}
```

The variable removal will potentially affect above.. Thanks for you help!

Sorry Guys, I was overthinking it.  For my instance this works:

```
New-Variable SinvStrWarning -Value "Warning! There is not a Software Inventory entry listed in the Inventory Agent Log file."

$InvFile = "$SMSAgentFolder\logs\inventoryagent.log"

Function SetSinv {
  $Sinv = Select-String $Sinvpattern $Invfile | select -Last 1 | % {
    $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value + ' ' + $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
  }
}

$Sinvpattern = 'SinvEndpoint.*<time="(.*?)" date="(.*?)"'

$Sinv = Select-String $Sinvpattern $Invfile | select -Last 1 | % {
  $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value + ' ' + $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
}

$SinvNull = $Sinv -ne $Null

If ($SinvNull -eq "True"){
  SetSinv;
  $TSSInv = (New-TimeSpan $Sinv).Days
} Else {
  Add-Content $verboseLog "$SinvStrWarning"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable removal will potentially affect above.. Thanks for you help!

Sorry Guys, I was overthinking it. For my instance this works:
New-Variable SinvStrWarning -Value "Warning! There is not a Software Inventory entry listed in the Inventory Agent Log file."

```
$InvFile = "$SMSAgentFolder\logs\inventoryagent.log"

Function SetSinv {
  $Sinv = Select-String $Sinvpattern $Invfile | select -Last 1 | % {
    $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value + ' ' + $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
  }
}

$Sinvpattern = 'SinvEndpoint.*<time="(.*?)" date="(.*?)"'

 $Sinv = Select-String $Sinvpattern $Invfile | select -Last 1 | % {
  $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value + ' ' + $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
}

$SinvNull = $Sinv -ne $Null

If ($SinvNull -eq "True"){
  SetSinv;
   $TSSInv = (New-TimeSpan $Sinv).Days
} Else {
  Add-Content $verboseLog "$SinvStrWarning"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function SetTSSinv {
  $TSSInv = (New-TimeSpan $Sinv).Days
}
```

The function creates a timespan and assigns it to the function-local variable `$TSSInv`, which is discarded as soon as your code exits from the function. If you want the function to return the timespan: remove the variable assignment. You may also want to make `$Sinv` a parameter of the function:

```
Function SetTSSinv($start) {
  (New-TimeSpan $start).Days
}
```

Comment: @user2755028 Please do not post code in comments. It becomes unreadable. Instead update your question.